# Python 2.6 + JCC + Pylucene issue

Tags: python, pylucene, jcc

Greetings,

I'm trying to use pylucene in Python 2.6. Since there's no windows build for 2.6, I try to  build the source code.

First of all, I build JCC (windows, using cygwin)

```
python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
[...]
building 'jcc' extension
error: None

python setup.py install
running install
[...]
copying jcc\config.py -> build\lib.win32-2.6\jcc
copying jcc\classes\org\osafoundation\jcc\PythonException.class -> build\lib.win32-2.6\jcc\classes\org\osafoundation\jcc
running build_ext
building 'jcc' extension
error: None
```

Notice that it won't copy anything on my "F:\Python26\Lib\site-packages" directory. I don't know why. So that, I don't know if it's really installed or not.

Now, I'll make pylucene

```
make
/cygdrive/f/Python26//python.exe -m jcc --shared --jar lucene-java-2.4.0/build/lucene-core-2.4.0.jar 
[...]
'doc:(I)Lorg/apache/lucene/document/Document;' --version 2.4.0 --files 2 --build

f:\Python26\python.exe: No module named jcc
make: *** [compile] Error 1
```

So, it seems JCC wasn't installed at all.

Then, I try to copy the "jcc build" under F:\Python26\Lib\site-packages, and I try to make pylucene  again:

```
make
[...]
f:\Python26\python.exe: jcc is a package and cannot be directly executed
make: *** [compile] Error 1
```

Has anyone else seen this and found a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

try:

> /cygdrive/f/Python26//python.exe setup.py build

and

> /cygdrive/f/Python26//python.exe setup.py build setup.py install

I believe you are using python from cygwin for instaling jcc and python from windows for running...

Answer (score 1):

Few checkpoints

- `error: None` mean there is an error on building, it was NOT success, so the extensions does not get build
- if you are using cygwin, I guess you need to use cygwin version of python, but according to this you using windows version, which is installed in F:\Python - `/cygdrive/f/Python26//python.exe`,
- I suggest you to try with [mingw32](http://www.mingw.org/), install mingw32 and try `python setup.py build -c mingw32` and `python setup.py install`

Comment: actually, that's a python 2.6 novelty.
I Used -m jcc.__main__ instead of -m jcc when invoking it. Now I got the following error: $ make /cygdrive/f/Python26//python.exe -m jcc.__main__ --shared --jar lucene-java-2.4. 0/build/lucene-core-2.4.0.jar [...] --version 2.4.0 --files 2 --build f:\Python26\python.exe: No module named _jcc make: *** [compile] Error 1 There's no such _jcc module - at least, I did not find any.

Answer (score 0):

that just can build jcc and install,

top full code.

13998bytes

when import,report error.

```
>>> import jcc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\jcc-2.5.1-py2.6-win32.egg\jcc\__init__.py"
, line 29, in <module>
    from _jcc import initVM
ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的模块。(cant find appointed modules)
>>>
```